# Cakephp option tag attributes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

In the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Ingredient');
```

The above populate multiple select list that HTML output as:

```
<select name="data[Ingredient][Ingredient][]" option="hh" multiple="multiple" id="IngredientIngredient">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Tomato</option>
<option value="2">Spaghetti </option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">Salt</option>
</select>
```

What I need to know is how to add attributes to the generated `<option>` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the controller to pass selected values:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') {
    // save form
} else {
    $this->request->data['Incredient']['Incredient'] = $ids;
}
```

See [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/)

To add additional attributes like classes you just need to make it a deeper array and you can pass those:

```
$options = array(
    1 => 'One', 
    2 => array('name' => 'Two', 'value' => 2,  'class' => 'extra'), 
    3 => 'Three');

echo $this->Form->input('test', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $options));
```

The result:

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="ModelTest">Test</label>
    <select name="data[Model][test]" id="ModelTest">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" class="extra">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

See [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/)

Comment: Sorry mark, I did not meant by the application data. I meant the `<option` tag itself. In other words, for example, how to get `<option class="someClass" title="someTitle">`

Comment: this is exactly what the second part here shows. you need to make it a deep array.

Comment: For CakePHP 3.x - you need to use 'text' instead of name in the options array to add the text value of the option tag.

Answer (score 1):

My Example custom tag option in select, by (CakePHP 2 + VueJs 2) is easy.

```
<?php
            $options = array(
                array(
                    'value' => false,
                    'v-for' => 'obj in data_options_input_id_vuejs',
                    'name' => '{{obj.text}}',
                    'v-bind:value' => 'obj.value',
                )
            );
            echo $this->Form->input('input_id', array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'input-block-level',
                'options' => $options,
                'v-model:' => 'productos_stocks_padre_combo_select',
            ));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Add extra data to option]

Hi all, In my case, i want to add code="code-value" to my select option and this code is working for me. 
If you want to add extra data to your option, try this code:

```
    //In controller 

    $chapters = $this->Course->Chapter->find('all', array('fields' => array('name', 'code', 'id')));

            // Call the noop function $this->noop() on every element of chapters
            $chapters = Hash::map($chapters, "{n}.Chapter", array($this, 'noop'));

// Callback noop function
    function noop($option) {

            $option['value'] = $option['id'];
            unset($option['id']);
            return $option;
        }
```

You can see document about Hash:map function [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::map). Good luck.